# Prove non-existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying for a while to prove non-existence of theu following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}$$

Unfortunately, with no results.

My hope was to show, that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}\not=0$$

But showing that was harder than I thought.

Can anyone show me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the second limit tends to $+\infty$, right? Because if you divide both the numerator and denominator by $2^n$, you get $$\frac{1 + o(1)}{\sqrt[n]{5} - 1}$$ where $o(1) \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$ and $\sqrt[n]{5} - 1 \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$ from the right hand side. Hence for the first limit, the subsequence with odd index diverges to $-\infty$ while the subsequence with even index diverges to $+\infty$. This shows the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\sqrt[n]{5}=x$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(x-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2^n+4n+6)\cdot(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})}{2^n(x^n-1)}$$
now substitute $x$ and get your answer to be non-zero

Answer (score 0):

Note first that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)=\ln 5,
$$
Hence
$$
(-1)^n\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}=n\cdot(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1+\frac{4n}{2^n}+\frac{6}{2^n}}{n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}.
$$
Clearly
$$
\frac{1+\frac{4n}{2^n}+\frac{6}{2^n}}{n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}\to \frac{1}{\ln 5}
$$
while
$$
n\cdot(-1)^n\,\,\,\text{diverges}.
$$
Hence, so does
$$
n\cdot(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1+\frac{4n}{2^n}+\frac{6}{2^n}}{n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}.
$$

Comment: You don't need that sophistication.

Answer (score 0):

Try to show difference bwtween $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup a_{n}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf a_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n(\sqrt[n]{5}-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n\frac{2^n+4n+6}{2^n}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{5}-1}$$

is of the form $\dfrac10$.

Comment: Unwelcome downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Divide the numerator and denominator by $2^n$. You dont need Lhopital rule .